# Power series coefficients

Tags: power-series

I've been trying for days now to find a closed form for the coefficients of the power series about $x=0$ of the function 
$$
f(x)=\exp\left(r^2\frac{x(n-2)-x^2(n-1)+x^n}{(x-1)^2}\right),
$$
but I always end up with an infinite series at best. Can it be done at all?

Comment: Here is the wolframalpha output for taylor series around $0$; $\exp(((n-2) r^2 x+(n-3) r^2 x^2+(n-4) r^2 x^3+(n-5) r^2 x^4+(n-6) r^2 x^5+O(x^6))+x^n (r^2+2 r^2 x+3 r^2 x^2+4 r^2 x^3+5 r^2 x^4+6 r^2 x^5+O(x^6)))$

Comment: Is it really $x^n$ in the numerator?

Comment: Yup, it's really the same $n$ that's in the other places...

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea, but a bit too long for a comment. You have

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{r^2}{(x-1)^3}\left((n-2)x^n-nx^{n-1}+nx-(n-2)\right)$$

So $f$ is a solution of the differential equation

$$(x-1)^3y'=r^2\left((n-2)x^n-nx^{n-1}+nx-(n-2)\right)y$$

Now you can try to plug the series

$$y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$$

And then find a relation between coefficients. See for example on Wikipedia, *[Power series solution of differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_solution_of_differential_equations)*

Comment: Ah! I did not think of that! I'm trying straight away!

Comment: This method is really nice, but I end up with a recurrence relation which connects $a_{k-2}$, $a_{k-1}$, $a_k$, $a_{k+1}$, $a_{k-n}$ and $a_{k-n+1}$. The only solvable one is for $n=0$, but we already know the answer to that..!

Comment: @Ziofil Not sure you can do better than that. In what context did you get to expand this in series?

Comment: The function that I wrote is a generating function, I wished there was a closed form for the sequence that it represents. I'm happy that at least I have the GF, though.